# Popup modal doesn't have a value upon clicking trigger input button

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a scenario:

Here's my HTML code:

```
 <input type="submit" id="btnpin" data-url="@Url.Action("PIn", "PIO")" value="P In" class="btn pin-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-article"/>

  <div id="popup-article" class="popup">
                                <div class="popup__block">
                                    <div style="overflow: auto">
                                        <div class="top-left-logo">
                                            <img src="~/Images/my-logo.png" width="270" height="99">
                                        </div>

                                            <div class="modal-top-right animated bounce delay-3s">

                                            </div>                    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='grid'>
                                        <div class='col modal-left-panel '>
                                            @{
                                                foreach (var m in DTR.Models.DataDetails.lstDetails)
                                                {
                                                    <div class="modal-left-text-container-top">
                                                        <div class="modal-employee-name animated bounceInLeft fast delay-2s" >@m.Name</div>

                                                        <div class="modal-employee-info">@m.Pos</div>
                                                        <div class="modal-employee-info">@m.Dep</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-left-text-container-mid">
                                                        <div class="modal-show-punch">
                                                            <div class="modal-show-punch-text">@m.PIO</div>
                                                            <div class="modal-show-punch-time">@m.IO</div>
                                                            <div class="modal-show-punch-date">@m.DateIO</div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                }

                                            }

                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col modal-right-panel'>

                                        }

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

And Here's my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnpin').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var punchIn = 'PunchIn';
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'punchIn':'" + punchIn.toString() + "'}",
            url: url,

            success: function (response) {
                //$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                //    punchIn = null;
                //});

            if (response !== null && response.success) {
                window.location.href = "#popup-article";
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                alert("Already P In.");
            }
        },
        error: function (response){
            alert("Error Message");
        },

    });
});
});
```

This Code is working fine but my Problem is i need to use `location.reload();` 
upon clicking the button `btnpin` because the value not showing if don't have this `location.reload();`

When loading the page the value is already fetched and done but when i click the button there's nothing else showing on the popup portion.

The problem of this `location.reload();`, the page showing two times and its annoying but the page and the value load perfectly.

How to make it with out using this `location.reload();`? it seems like i need to have some `.fucos()` on that particular `popup` class when the page is loaded.

Any idea is pretty much appreciated.

Comment: `async:false` and `location.reload()` kill all `ajax` advantages. You should handle `showing.bs.modal` event and populate `modal` data from `json` received.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKudryashev let me try this.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev do you any example in particular?